# No Output C# Finding the Factorial

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find the factorial of a number in C#. (The factorial of five is this: 5! 5x4x3x2x1) The console displays "no output" even though I requested to print a variable. Some syntax may be wrong, too.

I would like if you guys could try to not use a different thing like arrays to print a value. Please use the while loop unless I **need** to change the way I am doing this.

If you would like, you can use methods, but I prefer not to in this scenario. I do not think  a method is necessary right now. Share your feedback.

Does anyone know why it isn't working? Please comment to help!

`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace SoloLearn
{
    class Program
    {
            static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int factorial = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                        int final = 0;
                        int factorialCopy = factorial;
                        int five = 5;

            while(factorial > -1)
                   {
                        int digitMinusOne = five - 1;
                        int multiplication = factorialCopy*digitMinusOne;
                        final = final + multiplication;
                        five = digitMinusOne;
                        factorialCopy = multiplication;
                   }

                 Console.WriteLine(final);
           }
    }
}
```

`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're not changing `factorial` in the `while` loop, so it will either run forever or not at all.

Comment: Ok. I added some changes already, but my output was 320, not 120. (My factorial is five) Here, let me show u

Comment: @RainAviator [edit] your question. Don't add code in comments

Comment: `int five = 5`  really?????  I do wonder why I am not a C# developer..... If this is supposed to be "_correct code_", than ..... 

Comment: @Luuk, I guess you can do that in any language on Earth. XD

Comment: @Andrew: But if that will lead to good maintainable code, is another question.

Comment: @Luuk, I would bet my life that five will always be 5, so no need to maintain, LOL.

Comment: @Andrew: Did you see the line of code where it reads: `five = digitMinusOne;` ?

Comment: @Luuk LOL, nope. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just like [500 - Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448932/500-internal-server-error) said, when you use a While loop, you should always update the value of the evaluated variable inside the loop, so next time it evaluates the condition it can be a different result.

Plus I'm not sure if you're using a correct condition in your while loop. That looks like it's going to run forever.

I would do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace SoloLearn
{
    class Program
    {
            static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int factorial = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            // Init this in 1, to be able to do multiplication on it since the start.
            int final = 1;

            // You don't want to consider 0,
            // You'd end up with 0 every single time
            while(factorial > 0)
            {
              final = final * factorial;

              // Here you assign factorial to the next number
              factorial = factorial -1;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(final);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `*=` and `--` instead? Also the variable names are very misleading, `factorial` should be...  *the factorial*, not the number being processed. Hint: you also don't need to multiply by 1, you can save one loop cycle.

Answer (score 0):

There is 1 problem i noticed.

(1) you aren't changing the factorial in the while loop. it is an infinite loop.

Also, quick question. why are you making the program too long? You can just do:

```
using System;  
  public class FactorialCalculator 
   {  
     public static void Main(string[] args)  
      {  
       int i,factorial=1,number;      
       Console.Write("Enter any Number: ");      
       number= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());     
       for(i=1;i<=number;i++){      
        factorial=factorial*i;      
       }      
       Console.Write("The factorial of" +number+" is: "+factorial);    
     }  
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't work, but I do appreciate the response! In the comment section, I added some changes to fix not changing factorial's value, and now I get 320. Anything on that?

Comment: I fixed the error. should work now. LMK if it did please.

Comment: 5 is my input. I'm pretty sure the program didn't work for me at all. (Before updated) But thanks for your effort! Someone else has already answered the question.

Comment: I made a typo; I started by writing fact as the input and then kept going on with factorial. It definitely works now. Anyways, glad it was sorted and you got the answer you needed. Best of luck with your coding journey.

Comment: It's probably worthwhile noting that the traditional solution to factorial is to notice that `Factorial(1)` is `1`, while `Factorial(n)` where `n>1` is `n * Factorial(n-1)`, so you can write a Factorial function as `public int Factorial(int n) => n == 1 ? 1 : n * Factorial (n-1);`. That said, iterative solutions to problems often beat recursive solutions in C#.

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand this. I have made some minor changes, but it still works. I understand this way better.